# CSS: Container does not stretch to 100% width

Tags: css

http://jsbin.com/uqafo4

Please check the white area: it should go all the way, as I used `width: 100%`, but it doesn't.

```
#container {
    background-color:#FFF;
    background-position:center bottom;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 440px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your errors ( http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsbin.com%2Fuqafo4&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 ) prevent the page from rendering in my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `<body>` element has some default area around there, add this to the `body` rule to be safe:

```
margin: 0;
```

[You cant test the updated version here](http://jsbin.com/uqafo4/3), no space :)

Answer (score 4):

By default the `body` tag in some browsers have a margin set on them in the User Agent (default) stylesheet. Simple use

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

to remove this margin. You should also consider using a reset stylesheet, such as this one by [Eric Meyer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 0):

Following Yi Jiang's advice should solve your problem.

If you don't have a background-image, you can remove

```
background-position:center bottom;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

I would also suggest adding some padding, for example:

```
padding:10px;
```

but perhaps you're thinking about doing that already, only you haven't added the code yet. Or perhaps you don't want to use padding for some reason or another.